Convert a `std::filesystem::path` to all lower case
I want to convert a std::filesystem::path to all lowercase so I can find files of a given extension, "dsf".
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::filesystem::path = script_file_extension("dsf");
    for (auto const& dir_entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{"C:/Scripts"})
    {
        //  For fundamental feature, don't recurse through directories
        if (dir_entry.is_regular_file())
        {
            const std::filesystem::path     file_path{dir_entry.path()};
            if (file_path.extension() == script_file_extension)
            {
                std::cout << "Found script file: " << file_path << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

In the above program, I want the program to find "herschel.DSF" as well as "rice_bowl.dSf".
Do I need to extract the extension as std::string, convert it to lowercase, then compare to "dsf"?
I would prefer a more direct approach (least amount of code).
Note: a case-insensitive compare example is also acceptable.

The duplicates don't resolve my issue.  How does one convert a std::filesystem::path to all lower case?  Or how does one perform a case-insensitive compare with two paths?

Do you need to convert the entire path to all lowercase, or just the extension to all lowercase?

Only the extension.  I'm searching for files by extension.

q.v. std::filesystem::path::extension, std::filesystem::path::generic_string, and std::tolower using the std::transform in the example.

In my understanding, file system paths are not strings (they are file system paths). A conversion to lowercase letters would be an unnatural operation. However, you can convert a file system path to a string. And that you can convert to lowercase if you want.

Here's a example.  Windows (and its predecessors) have case-insensitive filenames or paths.  Iterating through a directory for text files (*.txt), I get a file with extension of TXT.  For case-sensitive file systems, they don't match.  Does the std::filesystem::path use case-insensitive comparisons?

But, on many (IMHO sane) operating systems/file systems, "foo.xyz" and "foo.xYz" are different files - but if you just convert the extension to lower case and compare, you'll think they are the same.. That doesn't seem right.

Does std::filesystem::equivalent (which, among other things, case-insensitively compares existing paths on Windows) combined with std::filesystem::path::replace_extension resolve your issue? You could do something like std::error_code ec{}; if (auto file_path_copy{ file_path }; std::filesystem::equivalent(file_path_copy.replace_extension(std::filesystem::path{ "dsf" }), file_path, ec))... Then it would correctly work both in Windows and in POSIX-like systems.

Have you tried using path::extension to get that piece, and then using path::compare on it? I would not trust tolower and other locale-supporting behemoths doing the same thing that the filesystem does; in fact, if compare doesn't do the right thing, I'd just use my usual ASCII-only case-insensitive compare... after all, most extensions that someone would look for don't need locale-support.
